# How to only return specific text from grepping

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep

I'm very new to Linux Bash scripting, what I'm doing now is finding the ERROR in a log file. How can I just return the time of each log instead of showing all details of it? The following is my code:

```
grep -n "Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception" error
```

One of the results from log file:

```
337:17:44:59,136 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobilelife].[default]] (http-/0.0.0.0:28080-32) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception:java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

And the result I want is just the time, 17:44:59, can someone help?

Comment: please copy/paste the text instead of the image so that answer scripts can be tested.

Comment: Wait, do you just want the time from each line, or the timestamp from any line containing `ERROR`?

Comment: I want the time from any line containing ERROR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for the specific text in a log file, for example: `Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception`, with many other entries in the file, you will need to eliminate printing for all other lines except the lines containing your search string, and then only output the relevant time from that line. You can do this with something like:

```
sed -n '/Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception/s/^[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*$/\1/p' log.file
```

Which basically:

- `-n` suppresses printing of pattern space
- `/your search string/` find the specific string in the file
- `s/^[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*$/\1/` obtain only the time using a
  back-reference
- `p` print that line

**Sample Log File Contents**

```
$ cat log.file
37:17:44:59,136 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobilelife].[default]] (http-/0.0.0.0:28080-32) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception:java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
37:17:45:00,136 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobilelife].[default]] (http-/0.0.0.0:28080-32) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service1() for servlet default threw exception:java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
37:17:45:01,136 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobilelife].[default]] (http-/0.0.0.0:28080-32) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service2() for servlet default threw exception:java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

**sed Use/Output**

```
$ sed -n '/Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception/s/^[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*$/\1/p' log.file
17:44:59
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to get only the match itself from grep is the `-o` option, so you could first find all the lines containing `ERROR` and pipe that to another instance of grep to get the timestamps:

```
grep 'ERROR' error | grep -o '^[^,]*'
```

The regex of the second command is "match from the start of the line (`^`) as many non-commas (`[^,]`) as possible (`*`)".

You could also pipe to `cut` with the comma as delimiter, printing just the first field:

```
grep 'ERROR' error | cut -d , -f 1
```

Or, to have everything in a single command, with the `-P` option for Perl regular expressions:

```
grep -Po '^[^,]*(?=.*ERROR)' error
```

where the expression in parentheses is a "look-ahead": the line has to contain `.*ERROR`, but it doesn't become a part of the match.

Comment: no, not only for this log record only, I need all of the time from log file!

Comment: What if there are 10,000 lines containing `Servlet.someotherservice()` in the same file?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is that addressed to me?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, sorry Benjamin, that was intended for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've updated the answer. As I understand OP, they want the timestamp from any line containing `ERROR`.

Comment: Yes, I see. Well, then I may have *screwed the pooch* thinking he only wanted the time from the line matching his exact search string. We'll let him clarify.

Comment: His comment says you are the winner..

Answer (score 0):

assuming the time pattern doesn't appear elsewhere

```
grep -oP "(?<=:)(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}(?=.*ERROR)"
```

or `awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '/ERROR/{sub(/^[0-9]+:/,""); print $1}' log
17:44:59
```